# How to create solid height field from image?

Tags: modifiers, displacement, height-map

I want to simulate caustics generated by free form lens using Blender and Lux Core Render as a geometric optical simulator. I know how to create height field surface from a gray scale image using displacement modifier. But what I need is the one with volume, cube-like mesh solid object with arbitrarily height distribution on the top face and flat plane on bottom face. Could please anyone show me how to do it ?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use the displace modifier for this, but with a vertex group to limit the influence to one face of your object.

1. Select the top face of a cube/suitable volume.
2. Create a vertex group in *Properties > Object Data > Vertex Groups*.
3. Assign the selection to the vertex group.

   [image]
4. Then specify that vertex group in your displacement modifier:

   [image]

Comment: I could what I want to do following your method !

Comment: I very thank your fast and kind answer with pictures :-)